# iOS - display a very long vertical stack view in landscape

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I'm having issues in trying to show a very long stack view in landscape mode.
I've read and watched several tutorials about auto layout and constraints, but I didn't find anything that could help me in this situation:

I'm using stack views to build the views of my iphone app; In one view i have a very long vertical stack view, made by other horizontal stack views.
I would like to find a way to show the whole vertical stack when in landscape mode, maybe allowing user to slide/scroll the page and see the rest of the stack, or maybe 'splitting' the stack in many part and putting them side by side in horizontal.

I made an image in order to explain better

[image: example]

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: if u want to slide/scroll u should use scrollview? stackview is just for easy constraint, if u want a horizontal scroll with dynamic cell maybe u will need collectionview

Comment: I don't think that scrollview is what I need because there are several different things in each horizontal stack view.. (eg. labels, buttons, switchs, images etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can change `axis` of `stackview` when device change orientation to landscape:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStackView *stackView;

-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
switch ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        _stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        _stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
        break;
    default:
        _stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
        break;
    }
}
```